# C++ inherit from a concrete class to another concrete class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to inherit from one of my class 2 variables which they must be equal to be able to return the value of one of my functions in the other class..

```
class Rectangle: public Shape{

    double Length;
    double Width;

    public:
        Rectangle(double Length, double Width):
            Shape("Rectangle")
        {
            this->Length=Length;
            this->Width=Width;
        }

        double getPerimerter(){
            return 2 * (Length+Width);
        }

        double getArea(){
            return Length * Width;
        }
};

class Square: public Shape, public Rectangle{

    double Side;

    public:
    Square():
        Shape("Square"),
        Rectangle(Length,Width)
    {}

    double getPerimerter(){
        if(Length==Width)
        return 4 * (Length+Width);
    }

    double getArea(){
        if(Length==Width)
        return (Length+Width) * (Length+Width);
    }

};
```

as you can see I have already a concrete class call Rectangle which hold to private variables with the names Length and Width.. What I'm trying to do is inherit this class to my class Square and if Length and Width are equal then I can return the Area and Perimeter of the Square..

Comment: So, what is your problem, exactly?

Comment: I don't actually know how to do it.. I'm not sure if I can inherit private members or access those two variables from my Square class.

Comment: You may access the inherited variables if they are `protected` instead of `private`.  That is the purpose of the `protected` access specifier.

Comment: Be aware that this class hierarchy may lead to a typical violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: To phrase @didierc’s comment more drastically: *this is a bad idea*. Your class design is flawed.

Comment: @didierc: To be fair, the code snippets above have no setters.  So it might be ok...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, yes, that's the reason why I changed it to _may lead to_.

Comment: However, I fundamentally agree with @Konrad Rudolph. But this looks like an early learning exercise, so I'll refrain from doing more comments on that. I just found it interesting that this code matches the example of he LSP.

Comment: You don't need to overload the rectangle methods: the formulas are valid for a square too; but you can  if you want to write "faster" version based on the square properties. Also, these methods don't need to check square properties: these should be assumed since the class is representing a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to inherit from an existing class.

What you probably want, however, is this:

```
 class Square: public Rectangle
 {
    public:
       Square(double Side) : Rectangle(Side, Side) { }
 };
```

That way, there is no problem of someone trying to use a ractangular square `Square(4.3, 9.6)`.

Alternatively, you could of course use `typedef Rectangle Square;`

Edit:

To overcome the "name", we could do something like this:

```
class Rectangle
{
    public:
       Rectangle(double Length, double Width) : Shape("Rectangle") { ... } 
    protected:
       Rectangle(double Length, double Width, const char *name) : Shape(name), Length(Length), Width(Width) {}
};

class Square
{
  public:
   Square(double side) : Rectangle(side, side, "Square") {}
};
```

Edit2: Code that I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Shape
{
private:
    const char *name;

public:
    Shape(const char *name) : name(name) {}
    virtual double getPerimeter() = 0;
    virtual double getArea() = 0;
};


class Rectangle: public Shape{

    double Length;
    double Width;

    public:
        Rectangle(double Length, double Width):
            Shape("Rectangle")
        {
            this->Length=Length;
            this->Width=Width;
        }

        double getPerimeter(){
            return 2 * (Length+Width);
        }

        double getArea(){
            return Length * Width;
        }

protected:
    Rectangle(double Length, double Width, const char *name):
            Shape(name)
        {
            this->Length=Length;
            this->Width=Width;
        }

};

class Square: public Rectangle
{

    public:
    Square(double Side):
        Rectangle(Side,Side, "Square")
    {    
    }
};

int main()
{
    Square sq(10.0);
    Rectangle rect(12.0, 4.0);

    cout << "sq:" << sq.getArea() << " rect:" << rect.getArea() << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if the Rectangle class inherit from a Base class a string can I inherit that string from my Square class too?

Comment: Setting the string may require a bit more "work". You could have a "Protected" constructor. See edit.

Comment: Yes, you inherit everything along the inheritance chain.

Comment: Well, I did it kinda different.. not too sure if the correct way tho.. I just inherit from Rectangle Length and Width and then did Shape cuz the Rectangle class inherit the publicity of Shape..

Comment: Can you show that code [edit it into your question, because posting code in comments never goes well]...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Wouldn't [virtual inheretence](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=393479eb4335d68b06fd2a0c3e3ebc9c-cc73e281b3b6abc9bf6cf4f153b944a6) be the normal way to overwride the `Shape` constructor?

Comment: I've never used virtual inheritance, but I was just side-tracked from my efforts to try to compile the newly updated code - I think `Shape` is called before `Rectangle`, which would cause the "Square" to be replaced with "Rectangle" by the constructor in `Rectangle`.

Comment: I just updated again and Im just inherit both classes.. I guess this is my way to go..

Comment: @MatsPetersson Not if both `Square` and `Rectangle` inherit virtually from `Shape`. The ctor of a virtual base class will (only) be called by the most-derived class (and before the ctor of non-virtual base class `Rectangle`, in this case). Question is whether it's really necessary to derive twice from `Shape`.

Comment: Please, someone that understands virtual inheritance, post an answer to show how that should work. I can't get it to work with my attempts. But it's definitely wrong wrong to inherit `Shape` more than once. Also, you shouldn't need the `Side`, `getArea` and `getPerimeter` in `Square`, as you can use the ones for `Rectangle`.

Comment: I have just confirmed my solution using a protected constructor at least works. I would also fix the typo in `getPerimerter` so that it is `getPerimeter` (no `r` next to the `t`)

Answer (score 2):

As a first thing you should add an argument to Square constructor, like so:

```
Square(double Side):Rectangle(Side,Side){
    // Add additional constructor code here if required
}
```

About returning a value in a constructor - that is a no-go as the constructor might not return anything.

I hope this is what you meant as your question was quite hard for me to understand.

Comment: Quicker than me... But it should be `double side`.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your question, but it looks to me like you only need to add a parameter to your Square() constructor.  It would look like this:

```
class Square: public Rectangle{

    public:
        Square(double dimension):
            Rectangle(dimension, dimension){
        }

};
```

There is no need for a conditional statement in the Square() constructor.  Creating a Square necessarily implies creating a Rectangle with equal length and width.